Generalizing Solovay's $\Sigma^1_2(a)$ measurability theorems to the $\sigma$-ideal of $E_0$-smooth sets
Solovay proved the following characterization of Lebesgue measurability of $\Sigma^1_2$ sets.

Theorem 1. For any $a \in \omega^\omega$, the following are equivalent.

Every $\Sigma^1_2(a)$ set of reals is Lebesgue measurable.
$\bigcup\{A_c | c \in L[a]~\text{is a}~G_\delta~\text{code for a null set}\}$ is null.
$\{x | x~\text{is not random over}~L[a]\}$ is null.


Likewise he proved the following analogous statement for Baire measurability.

Theorem 2. For any $a \in \omega^\omega$, the following are equivalent.

Every $\Sigma^1_2(a)$ set of reals has the Baire property.
$\bigcup\{A_c | c \in L[a]~\text{is an}~F_{\sigma\delta}~\text{code for a meager set}\}$ is meager.
$\{x | x~\text{not a Cohen real over}~L[a]\}$ is meager.


(See Theorems 14.1 and 14.2 in Kanamori's The Higher Infinite.)
In the study of Borel equivalence relations, there is a certain $\sigma$-ideal that often shows up.

Definition. Given a Borel equivalence relation $E$ on a Polish space $X$, a Borel set $A \subseteq X$ is $E$-smooth if there is a Polish space $Y$ and a Borel function $f : A \to Y$ such that for all $a,a' \in A$, $a \mathrel{E} a'$ if and only if $f(a) = f(a')$.

As implied, the collection of smooth sets forms a $\sigma$-ideal. For countable Borel equivalence relations, it can be shown that a set is smooth if and only if it admits a Borel transversal (i.e., $A\subseteq X$ is smooth if and only if there is a Borel $B \subseteq A$ which intersects each $E$-class of $A$ at precisely one point), so in this case we can say that the smooth ideal is the $\sigma$-ideal generated by $E$-anticliques.
There's a certain special Borel equivalence relation (on Cantor space $2^\omega$) called $E_0$ defined by $\alpha \mathrel{E_0} \beta$ if $\alpha(n) = \beta(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. What's notable about this is that by the famous dichotomy theorem of Harrington, Kechris, and Louveau, this equivalence relation is in some sense the minimal 'wild' Borel equivalence relation.
$E_0$ can be shown to be Borel-equivalent to the $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$ equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, the fact that the $E_0$-smooth ideal is proper is essentially the non-measurability of the Vitali set.

My question is about the extent to which analogs of Theorems 1 and 2 can be stated for the $E_0$-smooth ideal. The first issue of course is just that smooth sets are defined explicitly in terms of Borel sets. Of course we can always complete the ideal by stating that an arbitrary set is smooth if it is contained in a Borel smooth set, but it's not immediately clear to me that this is the 'right' generalization. I believe I've seen a definition of it for $\Sigma^1_1$ sets somewhere in the literature but I can't find it at the moment.

Question 1. Is there a good generalization of the smooth ideal for low-complexity projective sets (in the absence of projective determinacy)?

It seems likely to me that one of the reflection theorems is relevant here, but I'm not seeing exactly how at the moment.
Given the rest of this question, an immediate issue one runs into is absoluteness. If $E$ is a $\Sigma^1_1$ equivalence relation, $A$ is a $\Pi^1_1$ set, and $B \subseteq A$ is a $\Sigma^1_1$ set, then the statement "$B$ is an $E$-transversal of $A$" is $\Pi^1_2$ and so is absolute by Shoenfield absoluteness. This implies of course that $E_0$-smoothness of Borel sets is absolute.
Finally, some of the equivalent statements in Theorems 1 and 2 can clearly be adapted. I suspect that the smooth ideal doesn't have the uniform bound on Borel rank property that the null and meager ideals do (although I would be very pleased to be wrong).

Question 2. What does the statement

"$\bigcup\{A_c | c\in L[a]~\text{is a Borel code for an}~E_0\text{-smooth set}\}$ is an $E_0$-smooth set"

imply about $\Sigma^1_1(a)$, $\Pi^1_1(a)$, and $\Sigma^1_2(a)$ sets of reals? Is there some equivalence that is morally similar to Theorems 1 and 2?

